Apps script variable not being recognised
There's clearly some obvious error(s) on my part, but I just can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.
The variable called check in the code below is not being recognised in the If statement, and the If statement code following the if statement is being run regardless of the outcome of the if statement - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
I'm trying to check for particular text in one table and if its not found then run a prompt for the user to enter some text which is added to the destinationTable.
function check(){
var destinationTbl = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2daca31a7a8_0_9').asTable();
var textToCheck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2daca31a7a8_0_0').asTable().getCell(0,1).getText().valueOf();
if (textToCheck != 'check this'){
  let entry = SlidesApp.getUi().prompt(`${'Please enter your license details'}`);
  let response= entry.getResponseText();
  if (response!=""){
destinationTbl.getCell(0,1).getText().setText(response)}
}}

Heres a link to the file

valueOf returns an object. Ref I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In your script, as a simple modification, please modify as follows and test it again.
From:
var textToCheck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2daca31a7a8_0_0').asTable().getCell(0,1).getText().valueOf();

To:
var textToCheck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2daca31a7a8_0_0').asTable().getCell(0, 1).getText().asString().trim();


In this modification, valueOf() is modified to asString().trim(). Because, when the text is retrieved from a cell on Slide, the text might have the value of \n at the end of text. I'm worried about it.

Reference:

asString()


Thanks, you identified the problem perfectly, as usual. Not sure why the variable used by the if statement remains greyed out as though it has not been refered to - but it still works.
Also, incase others have a similar issue - make sure to only call UI when the document the script refers to is open or you will get a context error.

I think I was too hasty in my testing. The greyed out variable in the if statement does seem to be a problem. The if statement is not being evaluated properly, for some reason it returns true in all cases?

@Colin Wood Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed modification to your provided Google Slide, no issue occurred. I have to apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample Google Slide for correctly replicating your current issue by including your current script? By this, I would like to confirim it.

@Colin Wood Now, I saw your Google Slides again. And, I noticed that after you reflected my proposed modification, you changed your script. In your question, you use if statement of if (textToCheck != 'check this'){. But, in your current script, your if statement is if (textToCheck = 'check this') {. If you have tested it and you say The if statement is not being evaluated properly, for some reason it returns true in all cases?, this is the reason for your new issue. Please modify if (textToCheck = 'check this') { to if (textToCheck == 'check this') { and test it again.

In the original file https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-Nesucqz1yv5rgX-bg02JUVDMDOg1L0PqU1CUCk9ObE/edit?usp=sharing you can see the problem. When running the check function the dialog box is shown regardless of whether "unregistered" is in the first table or not.

@Colin Wood Thank you for replying. I checked it and proposed a new modification point. Please confirm it.

@Colin Wood About The greyed out variable in the if statement does seem to be a problem., the reason for this is due to if (textToCheck = 'check this') {. When you change it to if (textToCheck == 'check this') {, this issue will be resolved. And, the values textToCheck and 'check this' can be compared correctly.

Once again you've identified my error perfectly. Thanks

@Colin Wood Thank you for replying. From Once again you've identified my error perfectly. Thanks, I understood that your new issue was also resolved. In this case, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
